# Multi Master Slave Replication

Tags: mysql, replication, multi-master-replication

---

```
| Slave |
---------
/\
|
|
|
|
----------      ---------
|Master A| <------------| User A |
----------      ---------
/\
|
|
|
|
\/
------------        ----------
| Mastrer B| <----------| User B |
------------        ----------
```

When User B Insert to Master B Replication between (Master A&B) will be done but it would not be replicated from Master-A and Slave.
But when User A Insert to Master A All Replication will be done.
As my Friend Realized said when User B insert to Master-B it will be Replicated with Master-A but log file and log position of Master-A will no change so it can't be replicated from Master-A to Slave.

We were wondering if anybody could find out how could we handle this problem?

Comment: Either your friend is incorrect, or you forgot to enable `log_slave_updates` on Master A.  Check that?

Comment: Thank you so much. You give me a huge help